# How to add automatically keyword to taxonomies when a post published, and assign them to the post

Tags: taxonomy, metabox

How to add automatically keyword to taxonomies when a post published, and assign them to the post
for example i have in my post edition, a custom meta box, when you complete this input, a function should generate a group of keywords in background , and i want these keywords are automatically adding  to a specific custom taxonomy in that post when it published,
this is possible? 
i try with

> wp_set_object_terms

and nothing working great,
thx

*sorry for my worst english*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the save_post hook, in your hooked function use wp_insert_term as described here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term

Then use wp_set_object_terms on the post to assignt he taxonomy term you just created as follows:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

for example:

```
function my_save($post_id) {
    wp_insert_term( 'bannanapost', 'fruit');
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'bannanapost', 'fruit', true )
}
add_action('save_post','my_save');
```

The above code, placed in functions.php of your theme, would add the term 'bannanapost' to each post when saved, in the fruit taxonomy

Comment: You don't need to use `wp_insert_term`, the term is automatically created if it doesn't exist.