# How to make custom posts to behave like taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I would like to have a database of fashion models on my blog.

The models section will be located under `/models/`. There shall be a loop of recent posts with models as well as the full list of models names.

Singe page of a model shall have URL: `/models/kate-moss`.

Each model's single page should be a custom wordpress post, including basic description, photos and special fields like age and birth date, weight and height etc.

On the single page template below the description of the model there shall be a list of posts related to the person.

One more important thing: when an author publishes a post they should be able to simply choose the related person from the list with a checkbox.

In other words the person is neither custom taxonomy nor custom post, it is both. But how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a taxonomy, with terms that are the same as the custom post type. Then in your taxonomy template, grab the custom post type that has the same post name as the current term slug.

You can automate this slightly by having the celebrity term automatically created when you add the celebrity post etc

Refer to this answer for how to do that:

[How to add automatically keyword to taxonomies when a post published, and assign them to the post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/how-to-add-automatically-keyword-to-taxonomies-when-a-post-published-and-assign/1285#1285)

Comment: Would you be so kind and go into details? Sorry, but I can't understand the logics. I create a custom post of a model, fill it in with all the details and save it. It will automatically create a taxonomy with the same term? However then the content will be duplicated: both the custom post and the taxonomy will have different URLs. What I need is to have a landing page of `/models/` with a loop of all posts with models sorted by date or page views as well as full list of models, then I need a page of a single model `/models/kate-moss/`. Is this possible?

Comment: A custom post type and a taxonomy aren't the same, and creating a CPT does not automatically create a custom taxonomy of the same name, you need to register it separately

Comment: It appears you have broadened the scope of the question beyond what you asked. Please ask additional questions and break it up into separate steps

Comment: I surely understand that custom posts and custom taxonomies are not the same. Also I have not broadened what I was asking. It's all and the same issue.

Comment: Nevertheless I will try to edit my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> What I need is to have a landing page of /models/ with a loop of all
>   posts with models sorted by date or page views as well as full list of
>   models, then I need a page of a single model /models/kate-moss/. Is
>   this possible?

Judging from this, what you originally asked is not what you want at all, so any answer trying to answer it will not be accepted. Ideally I should flag this and attempt to close it, or edit your question based on what you revealed in your comment.

If you have a post type named `models` then add an archive-models.php in your theme and put your loop in there. That will be the archive for your models post type, aka your landing page.

Comment: Tried to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Posts 2 Posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/), which provides an interface for creating many-to-many connections between posts.

[posts 2 posts screenshot http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/screenshot-1.png?r=527690](http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/screenshot-1.png?r=527690)

Comment: That's not exactly what I need, moreover I would like to make it simple and without plugins.

Comment: @SergeySedykh How is not exactly what you need? When you add a model, add a term with the same name to a taxonomy so it can be assigned to related posts. Tom's answer contains a link to code which can automate this process. If neither of these solutions are what you're asking for, you need to clarify your question.